# Condition on another field into a sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `ticket` and `article`, I have this query :

```
SELECT hour(ticket.stats_iso) hour_num, 
       IF(MINUTE(ticket.stats_iso) < 30, 0, 1) interval_num, 
       min(ticket.stats_iso) interval_begin, 
       max(ticket.stats_iso) interval_end, 
       count(ticket.id) countid, 
       sum(ticket.montantTTC) sum_subtotal, 
       (sum(ticket.montantTTC)/count(ticket.id)) as moy
FROM ticket
WHERE ticket.annule = 0
      AND ticket.stats_iso
          BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-01 23:59:59'
GROUP BY hour_num, interval_num
ORDER BY hour_num, interval_num
```

I have statistics about number of `ticket`s and the sum of `montantTTC`.

I would like to have the number of `article`s then I joined :

```
SELECT hour(ticket.stats_iso) hour_num, 
       IF(MINUTE(ticket.stats_iso) < 30, 0, 1) interval_num, 
       min(ticket.stats_iso) interval_begin, 
       max(ticket.stats_iso) interval_end, 
       count(DISTINCT ticket.id) countid, 
       sum(ticket.montantTTC) sum_subtotal, 
       (sum(ticket.montantTTC)/count(ticket.id)) as moy, count(article.id)
FROM ticket, article
WHERE ticket.annule = 0
      AND ticket.stats_iso
          BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-01 23:59:59'
      AND ticket.uid = article.uid_ticket
GROUP BY hour_num, interval_num
ORDER BY hour_num, interval_num
```

It works BUT `sum(ticket.montantTTC) sum_subtotal` becomes false... (indeed, with the join it sums many duplicate `ticket` **because of 1 `ticket` has many `article`s**

`count(ticket.id) countid` has a problem too but I can write `count(DISTINCT ticket.id) countid`.

Does it exist a way to make a condition on `sum(ticket.montantTTC) sum_subtotal` ?

Example (of course, doesn't work) : `sum(if ticket.id IS DISTINCT then ticket.montantTTC) sum_subtotal`

[image: Example]

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT HOUR(t.stats_iso) hour_num, 
          ROUND(MINUTE(t.stats_iso)/60) interval_num, 
          MIN(t.stats_iso) interval_begin, 
          MAX(t.stats_iso) interval_end, 
          COUNT(t.id) countid, 
          SUM(t.montantTTC) sum_subtotal, 
          SUM(t.montantTTC)/count(t.id) moy, 
          SUM(COALESCE(a.article_count,0)) article_count
     FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT uid_ticket, COUNT(*) article_count
         FROM article 
     GROUP BY uid_ticket 
          ) a
       ON t.uid = a.uid_ticket
    WHERE t.annule = 0
      AND t.stats_iso BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-01-02'
 GROUP BY hour_num, interval_num
 ORDER BY hour_num, interval_num
```

Comment: Thank you, but `Erreur SQL (138): IDB-2021: 'article_count' is not in GROUP BY clause. All non-aggregate columns in the SELECT and ORDER BY clause must be included in the GROUP BY clause. ` And I can't add 'article_count' into GROUP_BY...

Comment: I don't have the time to check manually the result but values of `article_count` seems right ! Thank you !